# Create a Permanently Linked TOC in Microsoft PowerPoint for Mac

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, hyperlink, table-of-contents

I'm working on a very large PowerPoint presentation and have been hyperlinking each element in my table of contents (TOC) to a specific slide so it's easier for my readers to navigate. However, it is a living document (frequently updated) and every time I add new slides, my links get shifted.

Is there a way to make these links permanent?

Comment: Why are you using Powerpoint for that? Word will do it much easier

Comment: I wish I could!! Unfortunately I don't have any choice in the matter -- I am inputting into a corporate template. :(

Comment: Someone with a strong knowledge of VBA could probably write an add-in or a standalone routine to do this, but there's no way to do it using just the tools offered by PowerPoint itself.